# Safari 15.3 (Desktop) and WebM inline autoplay video playback Issues

Tags: html, video, safari, video-streaming, html5-video

A simple WebM video with the `autoplay` attribute set does not seem to play correctly in Safari 15.3:

```html
<video autoplay muted playsinline controls>
 <source src="https://www.homepage-helden.de/cms/test.webm" type="video/webm">
<source src="https://www.homepage-helden.de/cms/V/startloop/Homepage-Helden-Hamburg-2019-S_low.mp4?v2022-2" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

The video starts playing then freezes. When the playhead reaches the end it starts playing again. I noticed that when switching tabs the video unfreezes too.

It does not make difference if the WebM Video is encoded with the V8 or V9 Codec.
[CanIuse](https://caniuse.com/?search=webm) claims that Safari 15. support WebM videos in Version 15 since MacOS 11.3

When Safari in Verion 15 is given the choise between an MP4 and a WemM file it chooses to play the WebM file and fails.

Here is a video: https://filebin.net/l77ctp61v8gtje7t

Is this a known safari bug? Or has it something to do with the encoding? Or with HTTP Headers?

Comment: I don't have Safari (no Apple device here) but from research they say it is **partially supported**. I wonder if your WebM is triggering the missing "part" in partial. Try a WebM with no transparency settings and no audio track. You can use FFmpeg in terminal (or Handbrake with GUI) to create such WebM.

Comment: Partial support in Safari 15.4 refers to being limited to macOS 11.3 or later.

Comment: The webm video in your code snippet returns a 'not found' error. I am assuming this is not the issue you are flagging but it would be good to correct to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you @Mick. I have updated the video URL.